# Template files not working for archives and categories

Tags: categories, templates, template-hierarchy

I added `category-news.php` template file to the theme directory but it doesn't apply the template of the category but instead to the `index.php` file.

`category-slug.php` is the highest level of the template heirarchy of WordPress so it should accept the file. I tried also `category-id.php` and it also doesn't work. The same for archives template files.

However, when I use `single-slug.php` or `page-slug.php` it's working without any problems.

I checked that there is not any conflicts with the permalinks, it's a parent category with the slug `news` and the class of the page of the category is `category-news`. What can cause this problem?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What code is in this template?

Comment: It doesn't apply the template of the category as it should. I edited the question.

Comment: is this an actual category archive? Or a page template with a `query_posts` call at the top?

Comment: It's an actual category archive.

Comment: Everything you've described should work unless you're going to the wrong url or the term or taxonomy has an issue. Can you try flushing your rewrite rules by going to Settings > Permalinks and clicking save?

Comment: I tried to flush the rewrite rules of permalinks but no change appear. The same happen when I try to use `archive.php`, it doesn't follow the template but instead show the template of the `index,php` file.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code you currently have in your category template? It could help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand your question very much, but if it is a category the template file should be named for taxonomy-category-news.php or taxonomy-category_news.php

Comment: It's not a taxonomy of custom post type, it's a category archive.